# Cannot access PHP Basic Authentication variables

Tags: php, .htaccess, http

I had this question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51019627/php-basic-authentication-how-to-get-user-name?noredirect=1#comment89043905_51019627), maybe admins did not understand it correctly and marked it as duplicate, so I am posting it again, because I cannot access these variables as defined [here](http://www.php.net/features.http-auth). And so called duplicate question does not help me with my query. In my case when I call `PHP_AUTH_USER`, `PHP_AUTH_PW`, and `AUTH_TYPE` they are empty, `null`. Can someone please help me understand why? My .htaccess file:

```
AuthType Basic

AuthName "You need to login to access this page."
AuthUserFile /usr/local/..../.htpasswd
Require valid-user

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
```

When I do `var_dump($_SERVER);` in my PHP code, I see that none of these variables are set, why is that? Is it impossible to access these variables if basic HTTP Authentication used with .htaccess and .htpasswd files alone?

Comment: Is `$_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']` or `$_SERVER['REWRITE_HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']` set?

Comment: @Evert Hi, thank you for looking at my problem. No these variables are net set either.

Comment: I think its because my server is set with CGI. I found some workarounds for this, but they don't work either...

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: PHP doesn't get AUTH-variables because Apache doesn't send them to PHP-interpreter. Why?

This part will work for PHP-CGI:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
</IfModule>
```

Only if

> Apache won't pass it to CGI apps unless you compile it with the
>   SECURITY_HOLE_PASS_AUTHORIZATION flag.
>   [How can I use Basic HTTP Authentication in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150507/how-can-i-use-basic-http-authentication-in-php)

You should *disable* basic auth in *.htaccess* file and use it in PHP.
Manual: http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php